# GL_ERROR when rendering model loaded from gltf

Tags: javascript, three.js

Trying to get a model loaded from a gltf working, right now it loads the model but its entirely black and I get

```
[.WebGL-0x7f8f03050e00]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_ENUM : glTexParameteri: param was GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV
```

in my console.

I've tried two different models and both suffer from the same error. Switching to the webgl2 renderer makes it render the model without a texture but I still get the same error in the console.

My attempt:

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            loader.load('models/scene.gltf', function(gltf) {
                gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
                    if ( child.isMesh ) {
                        console.log(child.material);
                    }
                } );
                scene.add(gltf.scene);
            }, undefined, function(error) {
                console.error(error)
            });
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('webgl2');

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, context: context});
            renderer.gammaOutput = true;
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );       
            camera.position.z = 5;

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
            animate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated to a different loader and it seems to fixed the GL_ERROR.